# Combining Rows in Excel for which a Specified Subset of Columns are Equal

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have an Excel sheet laid out as follows:

| Software Name | Software Version | Is on host1? | Is on host2? | Is on host3? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 1.0 | Yes |  |  |
| app1 | 1.0 |  |  | Yes |
| app1 | 1.1 |  | Yes |  |
| app2 | 3.7.8 | Yes |  |  |

For every row above, **exactly one** of **"Is on host1?"**, **"Is on host2"**, **"Is on host3"** will be **"Yes"**.

On another sheet, I would like to generate the following from what is shown above:

| Software Name | Software Version | Is on host1? | Is on host2? | Is on host3? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 1.0 | Yes |  | Yes |
| app1 | 1.1 |  | Yes |  |
| app2 | 3.7.8 | Yes |  |  |

To state this in words, I'd like to have the column combination **(Software Name, Software Version)** be unique for every row (i.e. be a primary key in database speak) and then be able to look across the remaining columns to see which hosts have this software / version.

Outside of doing this manually in VBA, will any of Excel's built-in functionality do this?

(As an aside, this is a one-off situation I'm dealing with involving exactly three hosts. Given that, I do not have a need to address the issue of database normalization and split out a "Hosts" table.)

Comment: One of the quickest methods to accomplish this is creating a pivot table on your data. Rows would be Name and Version. Values is Host1, Host2, Host3. Change to Tabular format, repeat item labels. No sub or grand totals. Instead of displaying "yes", it would display 1 as a count.

Comment: Isolated, thank you--this did do what I am looking for. If you'll make this an answer (as opposed to a comment), I will accept it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer per your request, thank you...

One of the quickest methods to accomplish this is creating a pivot table on your data. Rows would be Name and Version. Values is Host1, Host2, Host3. Change to Tabular format, repeat item labels. No sub or grand totals. Instead of displaying "yes", it would display 1 as a count.